# why Jsoup split length of a string is wrong

Tags: jsoup

I am using Jsoup to scrap on a website , this is my program

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
public class JsoupExample
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Document doc = null;
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.123.com/xxx-sss-live")
            .timeout(10 * 1000).get();
            Element tickerEl = doc.select("div.tickerdata").first();
            String livedata = tickerEl.text();

            System.out.println("livedata "+livedata);

            String extract[] = livedata.split("   ");

            System.out.println("Length "+extract.length);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

The output of the program is this

```
livedata 7793.50   136.00   1.75%
Length 1
```

Could you please let me know why the split length is 1 in this case ?? where as this should be 3 know ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the **space** in the middle is actually a **non-breaking-space**. If you use the below code you will see that the result length is 3.

```
String extract[] = livedata.split(" \u00A0 ");
```